# Appearence of long labels on x-axis

Tags: jpgraph

I have really long labels for the x axis. They overflow at the margins. See here:

[image]

The outer right label overflows. It should be `r,r,r,r,r,N,N,r`.
Is there a way to display them vertical or diagonal like in Excel?

Another option woould be to make the spacing bigger around the graph but when I call

```
$graph = new Graph(600, 300);
```

the whole graph is scaled accordingly. How can I change that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can increase the margin around the graph:

```
$graph->img->SetMargin(50, 60, 50, 50); // left, right, top, bottom
```

Result:

[image]